# How to generate public and private key using TLS Certificate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, encryption, cryptography

I purchased a TLS certificate and want to use it for encryption. I have two services: one is encrypting a request object using the TLS certificate's public key, and the second service will decrypt it using the TLS certificate's private key. The TLS certificate is hosted on a private server, and both services can access the certificate from the server.

I am using X509Certificate2 to read the certificate and want to obtain both the public and private keys. I am able to get the public key, but it's not showing the private key in the object.

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateData);

            if (certificate.HasPrivateKey)
            {
    
            }
```

Comment: A TLS certificate is designed to be used in the TLS protocol. The TLS protocol handles all the encryption and decryption for you. Of course you *can* use it for other purposes but your description suggests that you are confused about the concepts. So, is there any reason you aren't just using the TLS protocol for your system?

Comment: Actually I want to sign a JWT token from a authentication app and want to verify does the token is generated by authentication app or not ?

To verify that I need a private key and I want to extract it from tls certificate hosted on a express server.

Comment: when I give a ```openssl rsa -in myKey.key -out myKey_private_key.pem``` it give me a private key. Same thing I want to acheive in my code using programmatically.

Comment: what does `certificate.HasPrivateKey` evaluate to? True or False?

Answer (score 0):

If this `certificate.HasPrivateKey` evaluates to false then that simply means there is no private key attached to that certificate. As @President James K. Polk pointed out

> A TLS certificate is designed to be used in the TLS protocol

Tls certificates issued by Servers only contain the public key and is used by the client browser to encrypt data it will send to the server in turn the server has the corresponding Private key it will use to decrypt this data sent to it.

More on this [TLS Encryption](https://www.ssl.com/article/private-and-public-keys/).

> I want to sign a JWT token from a authentication app and want to
> verify does the token is generated by authentication app or not

From your comment it seems you are trying to implement [digital signature and verification](https://medium.com/@craftingcode/how-to-use-asp-net-core-for-creating-and-verifying-digital-signatures-on-documents-47e639684003) and not encryption, Why not use [Openssl](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rpa/21.0?topic=keys-generating-private-public-key-pair) to generate your pair i.e private key (to sign the data) and public key (verify signed data).